# Permissions issue while installing Moodle

Tags: permissions, centos-7

I am trying to install Moodle onto my web server, but it can't create the moodle data directory, because of missing write permissions:

```
Parent directory (/var/www) is not writeable. Data directory (/var/www/moodledata) cannot be created by the installer.
```

I have tried to set chmod 777 & 666 to the www directory, but it still doesn't work...

**ls -al result:**

```
drwxrwsrwx+  4 apache apache   31 Dec  8 15:49 www
```

**Edit:**

My permissions for the www folder are just ultimately messed up, because i don't understand a thing about permissions could someone help me fix them up? I need to also allow sftp_users group to access the files:

**ls -al on www:**

```
drwxrwsrwx+  5 apache sftp_users   48 Dec  8 19:35 www
```

**ls -al inside www**:

```
drwxrwsrwx+  5 apache sftp_users   48 Dec  8 19:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root   root       4096 Dec  8 17:29 ..
drwxrwx---.  2 root   sftp_users    6 Aug 24 21:12 cgi-bin
drwxrws---+  3 root   sftp_users   35 Dec  8 19:36 html
drwxrwsr-x+  2 root   sftp_users    6 Dec  8 19:35 moodledata
```

Comment: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=164786 - scroll to bottom answer by Jason Vore... Do you have root/SSH access to your server?

Comment: Not root ssh access, but ssh access.

Comment: Very late response, but for other searchers: computer programming questions like this should rather be asked at StackOverflow.com (they actually have a Moodle tag)

Comment: I would disagree. This is clearly not about programming (though I understand why StackOverflow might have a `moodle` tag). Assuming this wouldn't be appropriate here (since the software under discussion is a CMS), it would almost certainly be more appropriate for the [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) (which has a `moodle` tag as well).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that selinux is blocking access. Check it with command getenforce. If the result is Enforce, then you may want to change it to Permissive, with command setenforce 0 or setenforce Permissive. You can also disable selinux by editing /etc/selinux/config and setting SELINUX = disabled. Reboot would be required in that case.
Also - is the directory ./moodledata a www directory for moodle or is it directory for file storage? If the second case, best is to move it outside the www directory, a designated directory in / like /moodledata and then set permissions on that directory for apache (or put this folder on separate disk or SAN share or NFS).